# OpenOffice Rounding: How can I make the displayed version of a number count as it is and not as it was before the format?

Tags: openoffice

My problem is basically this: I can successfully make the number 7,5 be displayed as 8, BUT it still gets calculated as 7,5 when I try to use it.

How can I make it count as it is displayed and not as it was before I format it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a formula to calculate the value you want to use (instead of just formatting the source value). For example, you can use the [**`ROUND()`** function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ROUND_function) to get the value of 8 based on an input of 7.5:

> `=ROUND(7.5; 0)`

Now, if you use the result in a calculation, it will use 8 instead of 7.5.

Comment: Function wizard --> ROUND --> number (the shell that the value 7,5 is) and what do I put on Function wizard --> ROUND --> COUNT ? I get an error if I put the wrong value on this last step.

Comment: I've linked the OpenOffice docs and added an example. If you want to drop the decimals (round to integer), the "places" parameter should be `0`.